# Reputation point in chat room different than actual reputation on Arqade

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

So, when I speak in a chat room, or look at my profile through a chat room, I see that I have more reputation points than I actually own on Arqade.

How is it possible? Are the reputation points in the chat something different than the "real" reputation points?

Here is an image of first above my profile on Arqade (the "real" reputation) and second below my visible profile through the chat room.

[image: Profile]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chat reputation is an *aggregate* of *all* reputation across all sites on the Stackexchange Network.

In addition to your 155 reputation at Arqade, you have 51 rep from two other SE sites.